# Can MacOS Dictionary be invoked by a URI?

Tags: macos, dictionary

I've seen links in web pages on MacOS and IOS that invoke other apps, notably App Store and iBooks.  If I recall correctly, they usually have a protocol¹ that in some way identifies the app.

I am using an HTML/PHP/MySQL app called [Learning With Texts](http://lwt.sourceforge.net) that allows it to create a URI to a web page with place holders to auto-insert a word to look up in an online dictionary.  Now I know that ⌘⌃D can be used on MacOS to display all instances of a string that appear in any MacOS dictionary.  I am wondering whether there is a URI syntax that will look it up in a specific dictionary.  (And what is that syntax.)

In Catalina, if that matters.

¹the first part of the URI—in a web link, the protocol is “http” or “https”

Comment: I don’t think that it can. When I was researching URLs for launching a man page (`x-man-page://`). I don’t recall seeing anything for the dictionary.

Comment: Thinking further, if it uses http/https, you may be referring to [Universal Links](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/386554/119271) that allows web developers to open associated apps with their links; like the App Store, Reddit, Imgur, etc.

Comment: It doesn’t use http(s).  Those are protocols for talking to a web server.  I’m looking for a way to interact with Dictionary.app

Comment: I know that, I’m not sure why you’d think I wasn’t aware of what http/https was for.  I was asking if they were links because of the last sentence in your question:  ¹the first part of the URI—in a web link, the protocol is “http” or “https” which of course is a footnote to your reference to protocols.  This is why I posted two comments - it’s not clear which direction you’re going in; the specific protocol or the universal link.

Comment: You can do e.g. `<a href="dict://foobar">Lookup 'foobar' in Dictionary</a>`, however, it will open it in the **Dictionary** to whichever was last selected when it was closed. It also pops up the **Do you want to allow this page to open “Dictionary”?** you'd have to respond to.

Comment: @Allan, sorry for any confusion.  Footnote was for anyone who wasn’t familiar with my use of “protocol.”  Seemed easier than interrupting the question for a lesson on how to parse a URI.

Comment: @user3439894: That sounds like an answer!  Only, it opens to "whichever was last selected" but then it immediately goes to the word in the URI.  Now if I could also filter it to the specific language …

Comment: Let me clarify my statement, "it will open it in the **Dictionary** to whichever was last selected when it was closed.", meaning whichever _dictionary_ (_tab_) was last selected when the **Dictionary** _app_ was closed, e.g. if **Wikipedia** was the _active tab_ when the _application_ was closed it opens e.g. _foobar_ there. For reference, this was tested under **macOS High Sierra**.

Comment: OK, got it.  Still sounds like a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can MacOS Dictionary be invoked by a URI?

Yes: `dict://`

Example HTML *code*: `<a href="dict://foobar">Lookup 'foobar' in Dictionary</a>`

Tested with **Safari** under **macOS Catalina** using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Dictionary Lookup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="dict://foobar">Lookup 'foobar' in Dictionary</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When clicking the hyperlink, one is presented with:

[image: Do you want to allow this page to open “Dictionary”?]

---

> I am wondering whether there is a URI syntax that will look it up in a specific dictionary. (And what is that syntax.)

If there is, I do not know it and I tried modifying `dict://` adding the different *tabs* in the **Dictionary** *app* and none worked.

The only thing that worked was `dict://` and `dict://` followed by the search word, e.g. `dict://foobar` and in the case of the later syntax it open to the last *active tab* of the *app*. For example, if **Wikipedia** was the *active tab* when the *app* was closed it opens e.g. *foobar* there.