# Get firefox on iOS, in desktop mode, to open links as if on a desktop? (and not open in another iOS app)

Tags: firefox, ios

I'm using firefox on iOS in 'request Desktop Site' mode. I'd like to open a link, just like I'm on a desktop.  Here's, it's a google sheet, and it keeps trying to launch the google sheets app.

That, in turn, wants me to log in, and don't want to do that, given the it's a shared device.

Is there some way to get firefox in 'Desktop Site model' to actually operate like it's on a desktop?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/386537/can-you-stop-websites-from-opening-apps